# Why do we say that $gcd (a,b) \le gcd(a, b-a)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I understand they're equal. I've proved it.

But why can it be the case that it is less than?

My number theory book says "$gcd(a,b) \le gcd(a, b-a)$, since the set over which we are taking the max for $gcd(a,b)$ is a subset of the set for $gcd(a, b-a)$".

I didn't quite understand this at all... Aren't they the same thing, therefore they should have the same set? Why is it that $gcd(a,b)$ is a subset of $gcd(a,b-a)$?

Comment: If $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a)$, then you must have $\gcd(a,b)\le \gcd(a,b-a)$. It never said it can be the case that it's strictly $<$.

Comment: A set is a subset of itself.

Comment: Rather: A partial ordering (like $\leq$) is among other things reflexive: $a\leq a$ for all $a$ or more complicated: $a\leq b$ for all $a,b$ with $a=b$.

Comment: But I mean, how is it possible that there *could* be the case that gcd(a,b) < gcd(a, b-a)?

Comment: @TimelordViktorious $a\le b$ doesn't imply it's possible that $a<b$. The reason your book says $\le$ is because it's a part of the proof of actual equality.

Comment: To expand on that: Suppose that we show that $c$ divides $a$ and $b-a$ whenever it also divides $a$ and $b$.  Then we know that the common divisors of $a$ and $b-a$ are a (possibly not proper) superset of the common divisors of $a$ and $b$, and therefore $\gcd(a, b) \leq \gcd(a, b-a)$.

Comment: Hmm.. I think I understand it. It's a weird thing to grasp. What do you mean "proof of actual equality"? :o

Comment: @TimelordViktorious In order to prove $a=b$, you can prove $a\le b$ and $a\ge b$. This is the method your book uses to prove $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a)$.